# Access to Distribution groups

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, groups

Is it possible to block access to an AD Distribution group for a user?

Such that he does not see the group, even if he is a member of that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide a DL from the Global Address list.  This would prevent any user from seeing it.

Edit the DL, and on the Exchange Advanced tab select the "Hide group from Exchange Address lists" check box.